# Find a subsequence with fastest time for specific distance

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, arrays, mathematical-programming

I have two arrays.

```
seconds = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, ..., 2680]

totalMeters =  [0, 3.2, 7.1, 10.6, 14.1, 17.9, 21.5, 24.2, 27.8, 32.5, 36.9, ..., 5000]
```

The `totalMeters` array is the total meters that I have run at this specific point of time. The sampling is 2 seconds.

I would like to find where in the array is the fastest 100 meters I have run, as well as its time.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really do that, and it's hard to pitch an answer at the right level without knowing what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generally get time for **exactly** $100$ meters with this data. The better approach would be to search for the longest run within some multiple of $2$ seconds.

**Find the longest distance run in $2\cdot k$ seconds:**

- Set desired `k`.
- Set `i = 0` and `j = k-1`.
- Set `currentSum = maxSum = totalMeters[j]`.
- While `j < totalMeters.length - 1` do

  - `i++; j++;`
  - `currentSum = totalMeters[j] - totalMeters[i]`
  - if `currentSum > maxSum` then `maxSum = currentSum`

This should also give you an idea how to build other similar algorithms for this problem, if you don't change your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an $O(n)$ two-finger algorithm for the problem in Python:

```
from random import random
from sys import exit

n = 500
vels = [1 + 10*random() for _ in range(n)]
i = 0
j = 0
d = 0
mv = 0
while j < n:
    # Scan until d >= 100
    while d < 100 and j < n:
        d += vels[j]
        j += 1
    # Flush extra.
    while d - vels[i] >= 100:
        d -= vels[i]
        i += 1
    v = d / (j - i)
    if v > mv:
        print('best: %.2fm in %ds %.2fm/s.' % (d, (j - i), v))
        mv = v
    d -= vels[i]
    i += 1
```

`vels` contains velocities for each time interval and is easily
computed from the `totalMeters` array. You can also adapt the code to
work on 2-seconds-intervals instead of 1-seconds-interval.